# Datatables 1.9.4 never calls Ajax method

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have just started developing with jquery datatables. I want to populate the table from data returned by a (Grails) server. At the moment, the server method is never called. My page looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/attendance/static/plugins/jquery-1.8.3/js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/trontastic/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />
    <script src="/attendance/static/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.24/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="/attendance/static/js/jquery.dataTables.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "/events/index"
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="example">
        <thead />
        <tbody />
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

No entry appears in the server log suggesting that the method specified by sAjaxSource is ever called. If I query /events/index manually in a browser, the method is called (and returns valid JSON), and this request is visible in the server log.

An alert placed before the call to dataTable works correctly. I used Firebug and verified that the dataTable call definitely takes place - although after that it obviously dives into dataTables code and I'm by no means a Javascript expert.

Am I making a really obvious mistake?

Answer (score -1):

Jquery.dataTables - it's a jquery plugin.

But in your example, there is no jquery library include.

May be it's a problem?

Comment: Hmm... OK, embarrassing - the jquery library IS there, I just inadvertently cut it out of the version I pasted as part of the question. I'll edit the question to fix that.